# Check whether a named textbox exist in the excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Platform : MS Excel 2007(MS Visual Basic 6.0)

I have a few excel file with different textboxes in them.
All the textboxes were name. E.g TxTbox_AAAA, TxtBox_BBBB
Most of them have similar number of Textboxes with same name.

I also required to update the content inside the textboxes. But like i said... some excel file doesn't contain the textboxes.

E.g aaa.xls and bbb.xls have TexTbox_AAAA, TextBox_BBBB
and ccc.xls only have TexTbox_AAAA

my script is something like this

```
xlApp.ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox_AAAA").Text = TxtAAAA
xlApp.ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox_BBBB").Text = TxtBBBB
```

but if i run, it will encounter run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the TextBoxes property of the Worksheet class

which i suspect it is due to the excel doesn't have this textbox named "TextBox_BBBB"

so how do i put a check before `xlApp.ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox_BBBB").Text = TxtBBBB`

to check if this worksheet/activesheet doesn't contain TextBoxes("TextBox_BBBB"), it will not execute this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a **TextBox** is a **Shape**, here is one way to tell if a specific TextBox is on the activesheet:

```
Public Function IsItThere(sIn As String) As Boolean
    IsItThere = False
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.Name = sIn Then
            IsItThere = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next s
End Function
```

Comment: hmm... i am not very familiar in adding public function into my script... so i can just copy and paste this function and edit the value into my script?

Comment: You could adapt it as in **L42** 's Post

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but try this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim shp as Shape

Set ws = Activesheet '~~> change to suit

For Each shp in ws.Shapes
    If shp.Name = "Textbox_Name" Then
        '~~> your code here
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helps

Comment: mine is the same as urs but the return value is as per stated.. "Textbox 1","Textbox 2","Textbox 3", instead of "Textbox_AAAA", etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks L42 and Gary's Student

I got it.. i should put

```
For Each s In xlApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes
```

instead of

```
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
```

only

Thanks for the help!!! =)